# How can I smooth out this corner?

Tags: solidworks

I am trying to make a punch for a die. This is really close to the form I want. However, I don't know how to smooth out this corner.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do your filleting at the end and use a variable fillet with a very small radius (like 0.01) in the regions where you don't want a radius.

Also if you use the merge option in your Boss-extrude1 you shouldn't need the combine feature.